# Python 3.3 nameerror name not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, nameerror

## Main file (robot.py)

```
from common.delay import PreciseDelay
from common.generic_distance_sensor import GenericDistanceSensor, MB10X3
from common.ez_can_jaguar import EzCANJaguar

igus_can = 1
l_actuator_can = 2

igus_can = EzCanJaguar(igus_can)
l_actuator = EzCanJaguar(l_actuator_can)
```

## Common folder contents

`__init__.py`

`ez_can_jaguar.py`

`delay.py`

`generic_distance_sensor.py`

## Traceback

```
C:\Users\Ethan_000\workspace\2014\aerial_assist\robot\source>python robot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "robot.py", line 67, in <module>
    igus_can = EzCanJaguar(igus_can)
NameError: name 'EzCanJaguar' is not defined
```

## Notes

`__init__.py` is empty
I use pydev in eclipse and giving an "Unresolved import" error on all of the imports

Comment: `class` is a python keyword, you can't have it in a statement like that...  I'm actually shocked that this is the error that you're getting.

Comment: i do not, that was an example, I'm sorry if that was confusing, it made more sense then the file contents themselves

Comment: then, I think we need to see the relevant contents of your actual `folder/file` before we can help you...

Comment: Always paste **real** code and especially **never ever ever fake output**. It can only make it harder to get help.

Comment: Please post a real, entire file which has this and the real traceback you get.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this, I updated it, if you need anything else just ask.

Answer (score 3):

`EzCANJaguar` and `EzCanJaguar` aren't the same thing. Python is case sensitive.